# No puedo crear nuevos archivos en Dev-C++ porque me ejecutan siempre un código anterior

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

Tengo un problema, y es que miren el siguiente código, no tiene problemas, solo está incompleto aún...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues ahí se ve claro, lo que debe imprimir son solo esas 3 cosas, sin embargo al ejecutarlo me produce esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya cambié el código a nuevos archivos incluso, para ver si era algún problema con el archivo original, y aún así sigue imprimiéndome lo mismo, puedo incluso borrar todo el código y al momento de darle en "compilar y ejecutar" o "reconstruir todo" me sigue imprimiendo lo mismo en la consola...

Comment: Cabe señalar que antes, cerré el programa que se ve ahí al lado "Ejemplo base de datos" que guardé de internet para guiarme y aprender de ahí a hacer una base de datos, antes de cerrarlo yo podía hacer nuevos archivos sin problemas en la ejecución, fue después de cerrar ese que entonces me empezó a fallar el IDE. Si requieren que les incluya el código de ese archivo también para decirme que fue exactamente lo que pasó, me dicen y lo incluyo también...

Comment: F9, si mal no recuerdo. Recompila y ejecuta. Seguramente estás solo ejecutando una versión compilada anteriormente de tu programa. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, te invito a repasar [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no se ajusta al formato esperado en [es.so], parece más una pregunta de cómo se usa DevC++ que de un problema de programación. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras No, ya lo probé, incluso también con la opción de reconstruir todo y aún así sigue ejecutándome eso, menciono también que incluso creé nuevos archivos para ver si era eso, y quizás si deba reformular la pregunta como dices, ya que no es una pregunta sobre como se usa ese IDE, sino que no debo ejecutar porque pienso que fue por la ejecución de un código que encontré en internet

Comment: No uses para programar un editor que lleva sin actualizarse más de 10 años

Comment: Utiliza code blocks, cuando Dev C++ me empezó a dar ese tipo de problemas y otros más (No me reconocía la librería iostream), cambie de editor de código, ahora uso Code::Blocks, su interfaz es mucho mejor y trae muchas más opciones, ademas de poder codificar para C y C++, y se puede usar el modo gráfico de C sin tener que codificar en Turbo C.

Comment: @Kate505 gracias, igual si tenia instalado el codeblocks pero como estaba acostumbrado a la interfaz de dev-c++, no quería cambiar de IDE, al final si lo hice, y me ha servido bien :)